# Printing a 2d array of coordinates in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print the array that I have created in the Lab12 class using nested for loop and the `getX()` and `getY()` methods that I created in the MyPoint class. However my loop is just giving me the reference. how do i get the values to print

```
pt[0][0] = (0.5, 1.2)

pt[0][1] = (0.0, 3.14)

pt[0][2] = (15.0, 27.5)

pt[1][0] = (6.6, 7.7)


pt[1][1] = (1.2, 2.1)

pt[1][2] = (12.0, 127.0)
```

```js
public class MyPoint {

    private double x;
    private double y;


    public MyPoint(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

}
public class Lab12 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    MyPoint [][]pointMatrix = {
                {new MyPoint(0.5,1.2), new MyPoint(0.0,3.14), new MyPoint(15.0,27.5)}, 
                {new MyPoint(6.6,7.7), new MyPoint(1.2,2.1), new MyPoint(12.0,127.0)}
            };

        for (int i=0; i<pointMatrix.length; i++) {
              for (int j=0; j<pointMatrix[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print(pointMatrix[i][j] + " ");
              }
              System.out.println();
            }

    }
```

Comment: you should implement `toString` method in MyPoint class

Comment: adding another method to that class isnt apart of my instructions so unfortunately i cant do that :(

Answer (score 1):

The best option, as @Lashane mentioned, is to implement the `toString()` method:

```
public class MyPoint {
    // ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
    }
}
```

Inside your loop:

```
System.out.println("pt[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + pointMatrix[i][j]);
```

Comment: my instructions say that in the MyPoint class i can only have the getX and getY method